# What would be the output of this php script?

Tags: php, oop

Can you explain, how this php code is working ?

```
<?=     
  _::
    o_O
    ()
;

class _{ static      

function
      o_O
      ()    
        {  return "Air is fresh and clean"; }           
}
```

Comment: There is no output as you can see.

Comment: Because o_O is valid function name.

Comment: Easiest way to find out is to simply run the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output would be empty, since the static function `o_O` only returns a string, and the caller does nothing with it. **edit** The output would be *Air is fresh and clean*, since `<?=` is a (not recommended) shorthand for `<?php echo`.

`_` is the name of the class `::` is the operator to call static functions, `o_O` is a static function inside the `_` class.

Rewritten with more descriptive names and better coding style:

```
<?php      
  echo Util::getAirString();

  class Util {
    static function getAirString() {
      return "Air is fresh and clean";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: But it's calling a function that is not even declared yet, how ??

Comment: That's not quite right. There would be an output since the short open echo tag was used `<?=`

Answer (score 1):

It's a class named `_` with a method named `o_O`, both valid names. `::` is the scope resolution operator; you use it with `static` methods. It helps to indent the code properly:

```
<?php

_::o_O();

class _ {
  static function o_O() {
    return "Air is fresh and clean";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?=
```

is shorthand for echo, you you would see that string.